# Short Example of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus Part 1

Tags: calculus, definition

I have trouble understanding formally stated mathematical definitions and theorems. However, I am still trying to memorize both parts of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Could someone please provide a short example of the first part?

I understand textbooks will often switch part 1 and part 2, but for the sake of this question, we'll say part 1 is this.

> If $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then the function $g(x)$ defined by
>
> $$g(x)=\int^x_af(t)dt \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; a \le x\le b$$
>
> is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $g'(x)=f(x)$.

Comment: E.g., if $f(x)=x$ then $g(x)=\int_a^x t\; dt=\frac12(x^2-a^2)$ and $g'(x)=x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental theorem of the calculus relates integration to differentiation.

The first part essentially says that the derivative of an anti-derivative is the original function.

For example, if $f(x)=x,$ then we can define $g(\color{blue}x)=\int_a^\color{blue}x t\;dt=\frac12(x^2-a^2),$ and $g'(x)=x.$

Make sure to write $x$ as a bound of integration, not part of the integrand.

Comment: Thank you! This really helps.

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm glad