# Fundamental theorem of calculus: ${d\over dt}\int\limits_{a(t)}^{b(t)}f(u)du$ and ${d\over dt}\int\limits_{a(t)}^{b(t)}f(t)dt$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I'm not totally comfortable with derivatives of integrals.

If ${d\over dt}F(t)=f(t)$ then ${d\over dt}\int\limits_{a(t)}^{b(t)} f(u)du={d\over dt}[F(b(t))-F(a(t))]=f(a(t))a'(t)-f(b(t))b'(t)$

But what is ${d\over dt}\int\limits_{a(t)}^{b(t)}f(t)dt$?

Comment: Cf. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3211731/short-example-of-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus-part-1/3211751#3211751)

Answer (score 3):

The latter is simply poor notation. In an integral like $$\int^b_a f(s)ds,$$ the $s$ is dummy variable used only for the purpose of representing what is happening in the integral (we are taking a tiny rectangle of width $ds$ and height $f(s)$, then we are summing the areas of all these rectangles). The expression $\int^b_a f(s)ds$ is not a function of $s$. Indeed, you've almost certainly learned that $$\int^b_a f(x)dx, \int^b_a f(y) dy, \int^b_a f(s)ds, \int^b_a f(t) dt$$ all mean the same thing. Later, if you learn about Lebesgue integration, you will commonly see this notation dropped, and swapped for something more like $$\int_{[a,b]} f.$$

However, in the bounds $a(t)$ and $b(t)$, the $t$ is NOT a dummy variable. The expression $$\int^{b(t)}_{a(t)} f(x) dx$$ does actually depend on the value of $t$: it should be clear that $$\int^{b(1)}_{a(1)} f(x)dx \,\,\, \text{ and } \,\,\, \int^{b(2)}_{a(2)} f(x) dx$$ are not the same. Since $t$ is an actual variable in this problem, it should not also be used as a dummy variable, so you really should NOT write $$\int^{b(t)}_{a(t)} f(t) dt,$$ since this notation can be confusing. However, if you see this notation being used, it is almost certainly intended to denote the same thing as $\int^{b(t)}_{a(t)} f(x)dx$, and whoever wrote it probably just got lackadaisical with their notation and let $t$ play two parts: the pertinent variable in the problem, and the dummy variable for integration.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Have a look at this link, it will solve your problems!

As for your question, this is the same as the above derivative of integral with integrand in $u$. $t$ is just a dummy variable for the integral, so we may as well label it by $\tilde{t}$